# nth-child code doesn't work

Tags: html, css, styles

```
body {
        background-color: grey;
}

table {
        width: 100%;
}
th, td, tr {
        border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
        border: 3px solid black;
        background-color: #F2F2F2
}
td {
        border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ff0000
        color: black
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #00ffff
        color: white
}
```

I've tried a hundred ways of rewriting this but I can't for the life of me get the 'nth-child' bits to work.  I'm simply trying to alternate the table row colors.  Any help in advance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the backgrounds on the columns, not the rows.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td {}
tr:nth-child(even) td {}
```

Will be sufficient to achieve what you want.

[Here's a jsFiddle achieving what you want](https://jsfiddle.net/6c8g15g5/)

Comment: That did the trick, minus the double 'odd' calls :)  Thank you sir!

Comment: @Addohm Fixed, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}
th, td, tr {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #00ffff;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

**EG: HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;Head 1</th>
<th>&nbsp; Head 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; Content 1.1</th>
<td>&nbsp; Content 1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; Content 2.1</th>
<td>&nbsp; Content 3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; Content 3.1</th>
<td>&nbsp; Content 3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; Content 4.1</th>
<td>&nbsp; Content 4.2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it.

```
<style type="text/css">
  tr:nth-child(odd) td {
   background-color: #ff0000;
   color: black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #00ffff;
    color: white;
 }
</style>
```